# Assignment of subroutine references in Perl script

Tags: perl, variables, subroutine

I'm learning Perl from Intermediate Perl by Randal Schwartz. Can somebody explain the assignment of the variables $callback and $getter in the following code?

```
use File::Find;
sub create_find_callbacks_that_sum_the_size {
my $total_size = 0;
return(sub {$total_size += -s if -f}, sub { return $total_size });
}

my %subs;
foreach my $dir (qw(bin lib man)) {
my ($callback, $getter) = create_find_callbacks_that_sum_the_size( );
$subs{$dir}{CALLBACK} = $callback;
$subs{$dir}{GETTER} = $getter;
}

for (keys %subs) {
  find($subs{S_}{CALLBACK}, $_);

for (sort keys %subs) {
my $sum = $subs{$_}{GETTER}->( );
print "$_ has $sum bytes\n";
}
```

Am I right in thinking that $callback gets the value of the first subroutine reference:

```
sub {$total_size += -s if -f}
```

And that $getter gets the second subroutine reference:

```
sub { return $total_size }
```

Is this a list assignment?

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list assignment. The subroutine returns two things. The first thing goes into `$callback` and the second thing goes into `$getter`:

```
my ($callback, $getter) = create_find_callbacks_that_sum_the_size( );
```

So, yes, your answer is right. Each ends up with one of the anonymous subroutines created in the `create_find_callbacks_that_sum_the_size` factory.